# Cookies are not being set because domain url is not matching

Tags: laravel, next.js, cookies, hosting, vercel

I have laravel backend and Next.js frontend hosted on vercel. Their links are like this:

- frontend.vercel.app
- backend.vercel.app

Frontend requests cookies but cant set. If i hover over error icon at right side on picture down it says "This attempt to set a cookie via Set-Cookie header was blocked beacause its domain attribute was invalid with regards to current host url"

[Picture of request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KJCc.png)

This is my env for backend:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.vercel.app
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=frontend.vercel.app
SESSION_SAME_SITE=none
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_HTTP_ONLY=true
```

I've tried `SESSION_DOMAIN=*.vercel.app` and it didn't work either.

Can I use `.vercel.app` as session domain? Or is there anything else wrong with this?

## EDIT:

[Blog about: Can I Set a Cookie from My Vercel Project Subdomain to Vercel.app?](https://vercel.com/guides/can-i-set-a-cookie-from-my-vercel-project-subdomain-to-vercel-app)
I think this states that .vercel.app cant be used as cookie domain. In my case frontend.vercel.app doesn't work as cookie domain either. So is there a way to share cookies between my frontend an backend with Set-Cookie, or what you suggest i try?